# Relationships don't work in Laravel(hasMany)

Tags: laravel

I have a Category model with key 'slug' and an Ad model with key 'category_slug'  and I need to get all related Category model objects

This code works and I get the associated model

```
$cityAds = Ad::where('city_slug', $sCity)->first();
$city = $cityAds->categories;
dd($city);
```

But, if I change first () to get () I get the error `Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance.`

```
$cityAds = Ad::where('city_slug', $sCity)->get();
$city = $cityAds->categories;
dd($city);
```

My Ad model has a relation

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'slug', 'category_slug');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cityAds`, when you use `->get()` is a Collection of multiple `Ad` instances, and your code doesn't know how to handle `[Ad, Ad, Ad]->categories`. You need to use `->first()` (like in your working example), or loop over `$ads`:

```
$cityAds = Ad::where('city_slug', $sCity)->first();
$city = $cityAds->categories;
dd($city);

// OR

$cityAds = Ad::where('city_slug', $sCity)->get();
foreach($cityAds as $cityAd) {
  $city = $cityAd->categories; // Do something with `$city` in this loop
}
```

As a side note, `categories()` is also returning a `Collection`, so `$city` as the variable name doesn't make a lot of sense. Consider the following:

```
$cityAds = Ad::with('categories')->where('city_slug', $sCity)->get();
foreach($cityAds as $cityAd) {
  foreach ($cityAd->categories as $category) {
    // Do something with `$category` in this nested loop
  }
}
```

Or, lastly, adjust your relationship to a `hasOne()`, if you're only expecting a single `Category` model, then do `$cityAd->category`